# Custom screen for confirm credentials on android

Tags: android

I've been adding support to authenticate user using device lock in my app, using the using [createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) api.

I am able to successfully achieve this and when I launch the intent returned by the above api, it shows the default android lock screen.

The question that I had is, can I modify the UI of the default lock screen that android shows? The api takes a parameter for setting title and description but can I modify other parameters, let's say background color of that screen?

I didn't found anything documented about this anywhere except the api docs, that's why posting here.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I modify the UI of the default lock screen that android shows?

No, sorry.

> can I modify other parameters, let's say background color of that screen?

No, sorry.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. 
Any idea if they plan to make it more customizable in future?

Comment: @Yashasvi: I would be fairly surprised if it were. The look and feel of that activity -- even whether the suggested title and description are shown -- is up to the device manufacturer. If anything, Google might try to force things to be more consistent.